# Unable to perform join raster-table ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I am trying to replicate some results from a publication. There, one of the datasets they use is WISE30sec map (available for download here: https://www.isric.org/explore/wise-databases). My problem is that even tough they state the following:

*"The zip file includes a raster GIS file (WISE30sec) as well as a range of soil attribute data files (see Appendix 3 of the documentation). Using ArcGIS® or similar, users may join the raster data to the derived soil properties files, as managed the MSAccess® database (WISE30sec.mdb). Linkage is through the map unit code or grid cell identifier (NEWSUID) of the raster set and the NEWSUID of the various soil attribute data files."*

I am unable to perform the above-mentioned join as I fail to find the grid cell identifier (NEWSUID) when using the Add Join function. ArcMap only shows the fields "ObjectID", "Value" and "Count" and none of them coincides with values shown at the tables I am trying to access. I have tried to copy raster and build attribute table but it didn't work. Also, when I put it in R, I cannot see these attributes that the raster is supposed to have.

EDIT: I am adding a some info, just in case they might be useful:

Raster properties:

> 43201,
>   1675310,0083333333,
>   0,00833333331,35
>   GBAIGGenericsigned
>   integer16
>   Bit-32768absentlevel:
>   7, resampling: Nearest
>   NeighborNoneBasicPermanent83,6249994416-180180,008331893-55,9833333333GCS_WGS_1984Degree (0,0174532925199433)D_WGS_1984skipped
>   columns:1, rows:1, ignored value(s):
>   0321560-10

Add Join function:

[image]

Comment: I've just downloaded the data you link to and I was able to join `HW30s_FULL` to `wise30sec_fin` by `NEWSUID`. So not sure what you have done? I did nothing out of the ordinary when I did the join. May be restart ArcMap?

Comment: Did you used ArcMap and the "Add Join" function to perform the union? Sorry I am quite new in GIS so maybe its just ignorance about joining data

Comment: I dont know... maybe it is about how I import the data into the software?

Comment: Yes that is how I did it, I followed your instructions, but I am working on a 10.6 machine. In ArcMap can you right click on your raster layer and view the attribute table? Can you see the NEWSUID field?

Comment: I do not. All I see is ObjectID, Count and Value.